# AWS EC2 ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat

my application is build with apache2 and tomcat under redhat in AWS EC2 instance. It work before, after I restart EC2 instance just can access thought ssh but can't connect in browser, and show 'ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT'.
Any idea what I make wrong or which log I should check?

@Dusan Bajic the httpd status seems normal, after execute `sudo systemctl status httpd` shows:

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-12-29 16:34:06 +08; 2s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 10891 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 10896 (httpd)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─10896 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─10897 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─10898 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─10899 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─10900 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─10901 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Dec 29 16:34:06 ip-172-31-21-170.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: ...
Dec 29 16:34:06 ip-172-31-21-170.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: ...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: If you can access shell, try `sudo systemctl status httpd`

Comment: @DusanBajic I append the https status in the question

Comment: Make sure that: 1) you are using correct IP address in your browser (or that you are using the domain name that resolves to correct ip address), 2) security group attached to your EC2 instance has port 80 open, 3) apache is listening on port 80 (`netstat -nap | grep LISTEN | grep httpd`), 4) OS firewall is stopped, or has port 80 open

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following:

- Make sure that you are using correct public IP address or Public DNS (IPv4) in your browser.
- Make sure that you have correct configuration in Apache configuration file, as  Listen IP:80 and  ServerName domain:80.
- Ensure apache is listening on port 80.